# Correct way to handle fragment's flow in the viewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have a `Fragment` with a `ViewModel`.

In the `Fragment` I have a `View` which exposes a coroutine flow and I want to handle the collection within the `ViewModel`, and obviously I'm not going to reference the `View` to the `ViewModel`.

My idea was basically at the fragment `onViewCreated`:

```
view.flow
    .onEach(viewModel::collect)
    .launchIn(viewModel.viewModelScope)
```

This works, but... is this a good implementation? Or is there a better way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use a standard fragment's scope not viewmodelScope

`viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` from `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0` dependency.

like this

```
view.flow
    .onEach(viewModel::collect)
    .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
```

Comment: I thought about that, but onEach is supendable, and that means the suspended block would be written in the view model but actually scoped to the fragment when actually the idea would be to launch it in the viewmodel scope (ofc I could create a new coroutine, but avoiding that)

Comment: The viewModel.collect is suspendable, but you can launch a new coroutine in the viewmodel with viewmodel scope if you want the code inside viewmodel to be executed in the viewmodelscope. I am affraid that if you launch the view flow in a viewmodel scope, you would be leaking the view/fragment...